# Trying to make an uptime command (converts to -1 day when after 12am) python

Tags: python, time, timer

ok so this works perfectly however after 12am it converts it to -1day which is frustrating because I'm not sure on how to edit it  to make it not do that.  How could I fix this problem?

```
from datetime import datetime


with open("bot uptime.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S')) # on startup of bot write the time in a file

timenow = datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S') # finds time now


file = open("bot uptime.txt")
startuptime = file.readline() # reads the startup time
print(startuptime)

s1 = startuptime
s2 = timenow
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT) # calculates the difference between the two times
print(tdelta)
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would convert the time into `%H:%M:%S`, losing information such as the day of the month, month, and year. If you start at `Dec 24, 23:30:00` and check at ``Dec 25, 00:30:00`, the fact that you're discarding date info means that the calculation will be:

```
  2020-12-25 00:30:00
- 2020-12-25 23:30:00
  ===================
            -23:00:00
```

(or some other negative value, I haven't checked in detail but it'll be *something* bad).

I'd suggest just storing the number of seconds since the epoch (in UTC of course, so something like `int(time.time())` should suffice) and then calculating the difference using that. This will take into account *all* the relevant items of a date/time.

Comment: I removed day of the month and year because i wanted to do an uptime  command, for example "the bot has been online for 30 hours 50 minutes and 10 seconds, ill look into what you said now :)